# How does a discord bot handle events from multiple servers

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm developing a discord bot using discord.py (rewrite branch) for my servers and I need to invite the bot to multiple servers and use it simultaneously.

My question is:

Do I need to set up a new thread for every server or does the bot queue events and handle them one by one? if it does queue them, should I just use that or use separate threads?

Sorry if this is a noobish question but I'm fairly new to discord.py and I don't really understand how it works just yet.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you just need to define the callbacks (mainly using [`Client.event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.event) and [`Bot.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command)) that the bot will execute when something happens.  All of the logic for listening for events happening on the servers has been taken care of for you. [See the examples directory in the discord.py project for some examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples).

If your bot is used very widely (hundreds of servers) you will have to start using sharding, which is a process of automatically splitting the traffic between multiple instances of the same bot.  You can look at the documentation for the [`AutoShardedClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AutoShardedClient) to see how that would work.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, it's much clearer now

Answer (score -1):

Multiprocesses, threads or queues can all be used to approach this issue each with their respective advantages and disadvantages . Personally I would use threads as the events that need to take place on each server are independent of each other mostly.