# Efficient Way to Run Multiple Instances of the Same Discord Bot (Discord)

Tags: python, bots, discord

I have a Discord bot I use on a server with friends.

The problem is some commands use web scraping to retrieve the bot response, so until the bot is finished retrieving the answer, the bot is out of commission/can't handle new commands.

I want to run multiple instances of the same bot on my host server to handle this, but don't know how to tell my code *"if bot 1 is busy with a command, use bot 2 to answer the command"*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the Python Discord implementation not inherently asynchronous? Is your scraping code written in a asynchronous manner or blocking? Can you simply start a background thread with a channel/... instance as parameter to post results back when the thread is finished with its work? This may be more efficient than starting N bots and still hanging on N+1 requests. Else, you may look at: AutoShardedClient. Or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558006/9360161

Answer (score 0):

The solution is something called asynchronous code.
This allows the bot to fetch the answer and go do something else such as wait for new commands before executing the next one.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

I recommend asyncio's python library.

Answer (score -1):

async function myFunction () {}

this should fix your problem

having multiple instances could be possible with threads,
but this is just a much more easy way

Comment: Please be add little more description to your answer. It doesn't really clarify it.